# Unable to get data from db using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, ckeditor

I have issue in retrieving data from db on click and put that data in bootstrap modal for edit. Its working where i have string in db but when array or i have field with html content it fails to load.

Here is code

```
    foreach ($unit_contents as $unit_content) {
         $default = $unit_content->is_default == 1 ? '(Default)' : '';
        $unit_content_html = $unit_content->content_html;

       <div style="height:40px;"><div class="block-options pull-right">
         <a href="#unit-of-content" data-toggle="modal" onclick="EditBlock('{{$unit_content->id}}', 
'{{$unit_content->label}}', 
'{{$unit_content_html}}')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a></div>
     {{$unit_content->label}} {{$default}}
     </div>;
        }
```

**Jquery**

```
function EditBlock(id, label, unit_content_html)
    {
        alert(unit_content_html);
        $('#label').val(label);
        $('#content_html').val(unit_content_html);
    }
```

I test it using alert it gives no data for unit_content_html while i have data in db and its as

**Coulmn Data**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I want to load this data in CKEDITOR;

Error on console is as

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

If i change column data to string it gives data in alert but not push even that data in CKEditor.

Please Help to fix thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code. And get data from server side in json format
`function EditBlock(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/file?id=" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
        $('#label').val(response.label);
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(response.html_content);
        },
    });
}`

Comment: Thanks for answer i am trying

Comment: from controller should i return response or json or just return?

Comment: return json response

`return response()->json($dataArray);`

Comment: dear it is very help and i am close to solution   If i have array like this `$content =  $unit_contents->toJson();
            $arary =[
                'form' => $content,
                'html' => 'test'
            ];
            return $arary;`  How can i use form in my view  as response.form.label or something else?

Comment: Try this `$arary = ['form' => "Content", 'html' => 'test']; return response()->json($arary);` and in ajax response use `response.form` and `response.html`

Comment: I mentioned `$content` a variable that have label and html_content in it `$arary = ['form' => $content, 'html' => 'test'];` then in ajax to get label how to do for it?

Comment: Check this link [link](https://pastebin.com/yZHrYWhx) 
Here is an example of ajax function where you can set values according to value you want to assign.
Use two below line to set content got from ajax

`           $('#label').val(response.form);`
`            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(response.html);`